# Compute the entropy of density function $\frac{{x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}$

Tags: probability, entropy

The question is to compute the entropy of density function $\frac{{x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}$.

First anyone knows what this distribution is? $x$ can only take non-negative values in this density. If $x$ ranges in $[0,\infty)$, then $t$ is solvable to be $t=\frac{1}{2\pi}$, and the density becomes $2\pi xe^{-\pi x^2}$.

Suppose $x\in[0,+\infty)$, then $ - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}[\ln x - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}} - \frac{1}{2}\ln 2\pi {t^3}]dx}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{x^3}{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{2t\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}}  + \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\ln 2\pi {t^3}x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{4t\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}}  - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x\ln x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{2t\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}}  =  - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x\ln x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{2t\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}} $.

Then I got stuck here. Any one knows how to compute the integral $\int_0^{ + \infty } {x\ln x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}} $? Thanks!

Comment: Just for your interest: calling $\frac{1}{2t} = a$ in the exponential, the solution is:

$$I = - \frac{\gamma + \ln(a)}{4a}$$

Now I'm going to work on the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:
This is as [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)

which can be interpreted as the density $\rho(x)$ of the length $x=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ of a vector $x=(x_1,x_2)$ with independent, gaussian distributed components.

Second question:

After clearing up the notation and trivial rescaling $x\rightarrow x/\sqrt{2 t}$ we want to calculate (there is indeed another part without $\log(x)$ which is easy)

$$
I=\int_0^{\infty}\log(x)xe^{-x^2}
$$

we observe that

$$
I=\partial_a \int_0^{\infty}x^{a+1}e^{-x^2}\big|_{a=0}=\partial_a J(a)\big|_{a=0}
$$

$J(a)$ is readily expressed in terms of gamma functions:
$$
J(a)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right)
$$

and therefore
$$
I=\frac{1}{4}\Gamma(\frac{a}{2}+1)\psi(\frac{a}{2}+1)\big|_{a=0}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1\cdot(-\gamma)=\frac{-\gamma}{4}
$$
where we used the special value $\psi(1)=-\gamma$ of the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

Edit:
This is indeed one of the integral reps. of the [Euler-Marschoni constant, given on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. Can you be more specific on this equality $\partial_a \int_0^{\infty}x^{a+1}e^{-x^2}\big|_{a=0}=\partial_a J(a)\big|_{a=0}$? $J(a ) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {{x^{\frac{a }{2}}}{e^{ - x}}} ,J'(a ) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{2}{x^{\frac{a }{2}}}\ln x{e^{ - x}}} $, then why this $J'(0) = I$? Thank you!

Comment: it follows more or less from the fact that $\partial_a x^{a+1} =\log(x)x^{a+1}$ and the fact that we can interchange limit and integration due to dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I know that. My question is that isn't $\partial_a J(a)= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{2}{x^{\frac{a }{2}}}\ln x{e^{ - x}}}$? Then why it equals $I$ when $a=0$?

Comment: this follows if u set $x=y^2$ in ur above formula, then set $a=0$